# "Could not access network location" error when installing blender

Tags: error, installation

Yesterday I downloaded Blender 2.79 from official Site: https://www.blender.org/download/Blender2.79/blender-2.79b-windows64.msi/

I recieved error `Could not access network location _\.` while creating shortcuts

I have network access

[image: error message]

Comment: Use zipped setup

Comment: I used zipped version but sometimes black screen appears

Comment: Autodesk has the same problem sometimes. See this: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Error-1606-Could-not-access-network-location-when-performing-unattended-installation.html

Comment: just install it from microsoft store